# PlaceFilter в google maps api places

Tags: android, google-maps-api

С апи я получаю данные ближайших мест, но мне нужно отфильтровать что б было только по барам и ресторанам, я знаю что это делает PlaceFilter но не пойму как его использовать, подскажите пожалуйста.

```
   PendingResult<PlaceLikelihoodBuffer> result = Places.PlaceDetectionApi
            .getCurrentPlace(mGoogleApiClient, null);
    result.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<PlaceLikelihoodBuffer>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(PlaceLikelihoodBuffer likelyPlaces) {
            for (PlaceLikelihood placeLikelihood : likelyPlaces) {
                Log.i(TAG, String.format("Place '%s' has likelihood: %g",

                        placeLikelihood.getPlace().getName(),
                        placeLikelihood.getLikelihood()));

                listForAd.add(String.valueOf(placeLikelihood.getPlace().getName()));



            }

            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            likelyPlaces.release();
        }
    });
```

Пробовал так, но не работает:

```
List<String> filterType = new ArrayList<String>();
    filterType.add(String.valueOf(Place.TYPE_BAR));
    PlaceFilter filter = new PlaceFilter(false,filterType);
    PendingResult<PlaceLikelihoodBuffer> result = Places.PlaceDetectionApi
            .getCurrentPlace(mGoogleApiClient, filter);
```